# composition of two continuous operators

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two compact spaces and $h: Y\rightarrow X$ a continuous map. Let $U:C(X)\rightarrow C(Y)$ by $Uf(x)=f(h(x))$ be the composition operator. Then $U\in B(C(X),C(Y))$ and $\|U\|=1$.

I know that the composition of two continuous is continuous. If $U$ be a positive operator I know the proof but how can I evaluate the norm of an oprator in the case of the question?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: You're using sup norm?  $|Uf(x)|=|f(h(x))|\le||f|| ||h|| ||x||$.

Comment: Yes, the norm of this space is sup norm.

Comment: I can guess it from the compactness of $X$ and $Y$, but just to be sure.  Btw, great user name.

Answer (score 1):

So $U : C(X) \to C(Y)$ is defined as:

$$Uf = f \circ h, \text{ for } f \in C(X)$$

$U$ is well-defined since composition of continuous functions is continuous.

$U$ is linear:

$$U(\alpha f + \beta g) = (\alpha f + \beta g) \circ h = \alpha (f \circ h) + \beta (f \circ h) = \alpha\cdot Uf + \beta\cdot Ug$$

$U$ is bounded:

$$\|Uf\|_\infty = \|f \circ h\|_\infty \le \|f\|_\infty$$

So $U \in B(C(X), X(Y))$. Furthermore, $\|U\| \le 1$.

For the reverse inequality, consider $f \equiv 1$.

$$\|U\| \ge \frac{\|Uf\|_\infty}{\|f\|_\infty} = 1$$

We conclude $\|U\| = 1$.